# How to change multiple combo cells in excel

Tags: excel

Iam new here so pls dont be mad if this is described problem:

In five cells I have list of five values. Then I have three another cells, which are combo cells. In each combo is possible to choose one of those five values.

I need to implement one another combo cell (also with those five values) with this functionality: When I change value in this new combo, all three combos above must change their values to this new value. After this, changing values in those three combos must be still possible.

How can I do this? Do I need macros or is there some easy way?

Thnx for help...

Comment: You create your last combobox, and you press "Assign macro" in the context menu. This will generate an "OnChange" event, in which you can do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

For the existing 3 'combo' cells you have, go to the Data Validation menu, select the Error Alert tab and uncheck the 'Show error alert...' option. Select OK.

[image]

This now allows you to enter any value in to that cell, and still have the drop down list menu.

Now you can go ahead and do something as simple as typing =F3 (or whatever the location of the new 'combo' cell), i.e. so that it will update with the value of the new selection, otherwise keep the value of the list choice. Example screenshot below...

[image]

Comment: When I set '=F3' as value to those three 'combo' cells, it works great. I can change its values by selecting value in new combo. But when I change value in only one combo (by selecting value by its select), then its value ('=F3') changes to this new value and then, funcionality is gone... Is it possible to select individual values in each of three combos and then change all its values by the fourth combo?